# R programming cumulative returns period calculations using data table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to request some help on how to create new columns of cumulative returns of stock data. My data is structured as follows:

```
Month      Stock    Ret
    
Jan-2001    A       0.01    
Feb-2001    B       0.02    
Jan-2002    B       0.01    
Feb-2002    B       0.03
```

The data is for 10 years. I want to calculate cumulative returns in 12 month increments for each stock.

For example, the first period of returns would cover Jan-2001 until Dec-2001. The second period would be from February 2001 until
Jan-2002 and so forth.

These calculations would be done per stock and would use non-cumulative returns for each period calculation. Since I have a lot of stocks for a lot of years, I wanted to see if there is a more efficient way to do these calculations than a for loop.

I have been searching for ways to try and do it with data.table package, but I am unsure how to do this.

## Edit:

Perhaps my loop function can better explain what I want to achieve.

```
my.data <- data.frame(Date = seq.Date(as.Date('2001-01-01'), by ='month', length = 24), stock = factor(c(rep('A', 2*12), rep('B', 2*12))), Ret = c(rep(c(.02,.01,0,.03,.02,.01,02,.01,0,.03,.02,.01), 2)))  

final_table <- list()
num_periods <- 2*12-12


for(i in unique(my.data$stock)){

  ts_i = ts(my.data[my.data$stock==i, 'Ret'])

  table_i = matrix(nrow=length(ts_i), ncol=15)

  num_periods = length(ts_i)-12

  table_i[,1] = ts_i

  table_i[,14] = i

  table_i[,15] = ts(my.data[my.data$stock==i,'Date'])

  for(j in 1:num_periods){
     myperiod = cumprod(ts_i[j:(j+11)]+1)-1
     table_i[12+j,2:13] = myperiod
  }
 colnames(table_i) = c('original', paste0('p',-12:-2),'p1','stock','Date')
 final_table[[i]] = table_i
}

new.my.data = do.call('rbind',final_table)

new.my.data = na.omit(new.my.data)
```

Comment: question lacks of reproducible example

Comment: Perhaps my loop function can better explain what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want yearly sum of Ret for individual stocks. First, I would extract years from your data by

```
df <- cbind(do.call('rbind',strsplit(df$Month,"-")),df[,c(2,3)])
names(df)[c(1,2)] <- c("Month","Year")
```

Then aggregate the data by year and stock

```
aggregate(df[,"Ret"],by=list("Year" = df$Year,"Stock"=df$Stock),FUN=sum)
```

Which produces df in this format

```
  Year Stock    x
1 2001     A 0.04
2 2002     B 0.04
3 2003     B 0.02
```

and It should not be a problem to visualise that.

Edit:

What about this?

```
aggregate(df[,"Ret"],by=list("Year" = df$Year,"Stock"=df$stock),FUN= function(x) {return (cumprod (x+1)-1)} )
```

which should produce something like this:

```
  Year Stock        x.1        x.2        x.3        x.4        x.5       x.6         x.7        x.8        x.9       x.10       x.11       x.12
1 2001     A 0.02000000 0.03020000 0.03020000 0.06110600 0.08232812 0.09315140 2.27945420 2.31224875 2.31224875 2.41161621 2.47984853 2.51464702
2 2002     A 0.02000000 0.03020000 0.03020000 0.06110600 0.08232812 0.09315140 2.27945420 2.31224875 2.31224875 2.41161621 2.47984853 2.51464702
3 2001     B 0.02000000 0.03020000 0.03020000 0.06110600 0.08232812 0.09315140 2.27945420 2.31224875 2.31224875 2.41161621 2.47984853 2.51464702
4 2002     B 0.02000000 0.03020000 0.03020000 0.06110600 0.08232812 0.09315140 2.27945420 2.31224875 2.31224875 2.41161621 2.47984853 2.51464702
```

This is reported per year, but I think you can manipulate and categorize Month/Year so that it fits your requirements easily.

Comment: Hello Marek, thank you for your response. The example you provided is not quite what I am looking for. I edited my question to include an example code of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think the *cumprod* function makes the calculation you would like:

```
taxes <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.3)
cum_taxes = cumprod(taxes + 1) - 1
```

So, the trick part of the problem is to break your data into the desired chunks, which are the different years.
The *split* function is a good option:
(just let me convert string date values to *Date* type and order them, before the spliting...)

```
df <- tibble(a = c('1991-10-01', '1991-11-01', '1991-12-01', '1992-01-01','1992-02-01'), 
              b = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.4))
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    a = as.Date(a),
    y = year(a)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(
    a
  )

split_df <- split(df, df$y)
```

Now, we can apply the *cumprod* for each subset of data.
As *split_df* is a list, we would like to do this (same as above) for each list element.

```
split_df[[1]]$cum_taxes = cumprod(split_df[[1]]$b + 1) - 1

split_df[[2]]$cum_taxes = cumprod(split_df[[2]]$b + 1) - 1
```

But this is no good solution for repetition, instead lets use the tidyverse *map* and *map2* functions do the job:

```
cum_taxes <- map(split_df, ~(cumprod(.x$b + 1) - 1))
merged_df <- map2(split_df, cum_taxes, ~tibble(.x, cum_taxes=.y))
df <- do.call(rbind, merged_df)
```

Or... in one chunk...

```
df <- tibble(a = c('1991-10-01', '1991-11-01', '1991-12-01', '1992-01-01','1992-02-01'), 
              b = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 1.2, 1.4))
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    a = as.Date(a),
    y = year(a)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(
    a
  )
split_df <- split(df, df$y)

cum_taxes <- map(split_df, ~(cumprod(.$b + 1) - 1))
df <- do.call(rbind, 
              map2(split_df, cum_taxes, ~tibble(.x, cum_taxes=.y)))
```